# how to create dynamic disk mirror in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mirroring, disk-management, dynamic-disk

I have 2x 16TB HDDs. One of them has data on it and is a dynamic disk. The other is unformated. It has one giant 16TB unallocated partition.

In Disk Management, right clicking on the disk with data has the "New Mirrored Volume" option grayed out:

[image]

I can select the "New Mirrored Volume" option from the unallocated disk but when I do I can't get past the first dialog:

[image]

(note how the Next button is grayed out)

So how do I create a mirrored dynamic disk?

Comment: If the new partition is really unallocated, try deleting the unallocated partition and then create the mirror from the existing disk, selecting the empty space when prompted to.

Comment: @DavidMackintosh - it's not giving me a delete option for the unallocated partition. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEGPE.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp4Ub.png

Comment: For New Mirrored Volume, both volumes should be unallocated. See the procedure in detail [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-mirrored-volume-file-redundancy-windows-10).

Comment: Seems like somebody else wrote up my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Backup the data on your D: drive
2. Right click the D: volume on disk one and select "Delete Volume"
3. Create New Mirrored Volume
4. Restore the data from Step #1 back to the new volume